# SharePoint Connector is not working in ping identity

Tags: sharepoint, single-sign-on, federated-identity, amazon-iam, pingfederate

Hi i am trying to make federation between Ping Identity to Sharepoint,am following the step given by the ping identity but still its not working. It is showing error like Error - Single sign on. Please help me to sought out this issue.

Link : http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/SPS24/Installing+and+Configuring+the+PingFederate+IIS+Agent

Regards,
Sunil

Comment: Sunil -- Not nearly enough info to assist. What component is throwing that error? What version of Sharepoint are you using? Newer versions require the use WS-Fed IIRC and will not work with the IIS Kit. You'll need to provide much info and clarity.

Comment: Ian - Thanks for ur reply. Created one idp adapter and sp adapter done the idp and sp configuration. When i hit sp initiated url it will load the idp log in url after giving the user credentials successfully it will redirect to the page given in the sp configuration. Now i am trying to protect the share point start page it is redirect to idp log in page after giving the credentials it say the error.
Note : I am using Sharepoint 2010 version.

Comment: Ian - Got this error message only - Error - Single Sign-On
Could not obtain attributes from OpenToken, please make sure the agent service has been started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per this answer at Ping Identity - you cannot use the Sharepoint Integration Kit with SP2010 due to changes in Sharepoint. https://www.pingidentity.com/support/solutions/index.cfm/SharePoint-Integration-Kit-FAQ

I would recommend contacting Ping Identity as I believe they have more info on how to setup SSO to Sharepoint using WS-Federation.

--ikb